# I am not sure why my program keeps on crashing

Tags: java, android

I managed to change something in the code and I am no expert in java but I have no idea how and where the problem is. The app lets me log in but crashes before anything actually pops up.

I have tried undoing the mistakes that I have made but still nothing

```
package com.example.dksimplelogin;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class Welcome extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView mTextMessage;
    private Button Logout;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);


        Logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                logout();
            }
        });
    }

    private void logout()
    {
        firebaseAuth.signOut();
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(Welcome.this, MainActivity.class));
    }

    private void account()
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(Welcome.this, account.class));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case  R.id.LogoutMenu:
            {
                logout();
            }
            case  R.id.ProfileMenu:
            {
                account();
            }
            case R.id.SettingsMenu:
            {

            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    }
```

Debug log

> 26/07/2019 10:42  Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
>
> 10:43 Gradle build finished in 32 s 28 ms
>
> 10:43 Session 'app': Error Launching activity
>
> 10:43 Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
>
> 10:43 Gradle build finished in 4 s 275 ms
>
> 10:50 Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0
>
> 10:54 Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
>
> 10:54 Gradle build finished in 2 s 726 ms

Comment: Doesn't seem to be crashing since it exits with code `0` which means the program just ends because it simply has completed its task

Comment: you havent initialized you button and firebase auth object

Comment: calling the methods on object without initialising it would cause a null pointer exception and of course the app will crash.

Answer (score 0):

Initiate the button instance with findViewbyId then try for Logout as

```
     Logout=(Button)findViewbyId(/*your button id*/);
     Logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            logout();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add few lines of code inside the the onCreate method..

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);



    //Add these to initialize the objects 

    mTextMessage = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name_of_textview_in_xml); 
    Logout = (Button)findViewById(R.id.name_of_button_in_xml);
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    // Add the above lines to your code      


    Logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            logout();
        }
    });
}
```

**NOTE:**  *name_of_textview_in_xml* with the actual id given inside your Layout xml file
Similarly Replace *name_of_button_in_xml* with the actual id given inside your Layout xml file

Comment: why two different auth variable?

Comment: the one who asked the question had two auth variables .. i dont know why he uses it. the complete code is not shown still.. there is no harm initialising and better to be initialized... So that any nullPointerException can be prevented that could be caused by invoking a method on an object that is not initialised.. :) @Ashish